# How to avoid problems with diacritics once and for all

Tags: unicode, characters, r, listingsutf8, rnw

I work with Rnw, and I type in Catalan, so there are diacritics I wouldn't encounter in English. I just want two things:

1. That when I compile my PDF, all diacritic letters are as they should be.
2. That when I save my document and open it again some other day all of their characters are in place.

The first one seems to be solvable using `\usepackage[catalan]{babel}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, but the second problem is still there.

Is there any way I could obtain this?

Comment: I don't know what would cause (2), but make sure to actually save your document as UTF-8. Other than that, switching to a unicode engine like XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX will of course save some trouble (concerning diacritics, it may cause different problems).

Comment: What are you using to edit your .Rnw files? RStudio?  Make sure that the default text encoding for files is UTF-8. (Set this in Preferences -> Code -> Saving).

Comment: If you use emacs, you can put `% -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file, or add it to the file variables at the end (e.g., `%%% Local Variables:` `%%% coding: utf-8-unix` `%%% mode: latex` `%%% TeX-engine: luatex` `%%% TeX-master: t` `%%% End:`).

Comment: Whoever voted to close: please give the OP time to respond to the comments. This post is only 2 hours old. And it's helpful to add a comment if you vote to close explaining why.

Comment: I've put "save with encoding", chosen "UTF-8" and "set it as default encoding for source files", now when I close the program and open it again all diacritics are perfectly in place. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your source code comes out garbled when you reopen the file, the chances are it was saved in a different encoding from the one that it opened in.  This is something you need to fix with your editor:

1. Resave the file with the UTF-8 encoding.
2. Make sure the default encoding in your editor is set to UTF-8 also.

Since you don't say which editor you are using we can't give more detailed instructions than that.